# Creating database using already prepared migrations ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 project from GitHub, but there is nothing in `App_Data`. I have all models, migrations etc... I'm sure that everything works. I'd like to create database to use this project. How can I create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [PowerShell command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#generating--running-migrations) that comes with Entity Framework Code First which updates the database based on the migrations in the project:

> **Update-Database** will apply any pending migrations to the database

You can run this easily from within Visual Studio using the **Package Manager Console** (**Tools** –> **Library Package Manager** –> **Package Manager Console**). Make sure to select the project that contains the DbContext class as Startup Project in Solution Explorer as well as Default Project in Package Manager Console, before running the `Update-Database` command. Also ensure you have defined a connection string for a local database that the command will update.

For more details follow the instructions in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/).

Comment: I tried update-database but didnt check before it rest information which you wrote. I'll try, thank you.